# Android:how to remove the padding between the bottom input section and bottom margin of an edittext

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

It seems there is a padding  between the bottom input section and bottom margin of an edittext by default. I have a linearlayout(horizon) including one edittext and one button. I just can't make them in one single line perfectly, since the padding between the bottom input section and bottom margin make the edittext lower than the button through I set the same height and alignment for them.

I also tried Relative layout but cannot solve the problem either, here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/SearchLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/FilterEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SearchButton"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/search_or_add_a_place"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/search_btn"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: then change the height of button.increase it little bit.

Comment: That's a tricky way, but if the resolution change the problem may re-appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changing the background of editText can solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

i prefer relative layout and if you write android:layout_toLeft or android:layout_toRight it puts them beside correctly but even after that it doesnt, there is ALIGN_TOP or ALIGN_BOTTOM or ALIGN_BASELINE.

I had the same problem as you and turned to relative layout. Its easier to me.

Comment: Thanks, But I need to use the layout_weight, since the button width is fixed by the edittext can be re-sized according the situation of the screen. The 2 element should fill the parent width.

Comment: If i understood well ehat you want to do you can do the following. Add the button with width 'wrap_content' add the textview toLeft or toRight with width 'fill_parent' . That will add them beside and the textview will grab the whole screen except where the button.is

Comment: oh and you can use layout_weight in relative layout too.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I tried relative layout. The same situation with linear layout. The edittext in the left looks lower(at the bottom) than the button.

Comment: I add my layout(according to your suggestion) to the question, you can check.

Comment: TRY Adding 'ALIGN_BASELINE' or ALIGN_BOTTOM in your button.and give the id of your textview

Comment: hmm, the ALIGN_BASELINE seems better, they seems to appear in the same vertical baseline. But the the padding at the bottom of edittexit still exist, which make it look a little lower than the button, through I set the same height for them. I think it will be better if we know the size of the padding(since we cannot remove it), than I can adjust the height of the button according. Again, thanks for your reply.

Comment: It seems the padding at the bottom of editText is by default from Google. And I don't find any API can remove it.